# How to use SizedBox in ListView.buider?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: i want each of them has height box]

```
 body: ListView.builder(
```

> // i do not know where should i put the sizedBox to make these image has space to separate

```
            itemCount: a.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: ListTile(title: (a[index][0])),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => a[index][1]));
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ListView.separated`, it has a `separatorBuilder` property that will help you to add the `SizedBox`, here the example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: 10,  // add the length of the array of items, for example data.length
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Text('Hola $index'),  // here build the cards body
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const SizedBox(height: 15),  // here the SizedBoxed
            ),
    );
  }
```